# Dynamic string cutting

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

Okay, so I have a filepath with a variable prefix...

C:\Users\susan ivey\Documents\VKS Projects\secc-electron\src\views\main.jade

... now this path will be different for whatever computer I'm working on...

is there a way to traverse the string up to say 'secc-electron\', and drop it and everything before it while preserving the rest of it? I'm familiar with converting strings to arrays to manipulate elements contained within delimiters, but this is a problem that I have yet to come up with an answer to... would there be some sort of regex solution instead? I'm not that great with regex so I wouldn't know where to begin...

Comment: First, n matter what solution you use, you must specify which part you want to keep and what  to throw away. I mean, what is the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Regex you can do:

```
var myPath = 'C:\Users\susan ivey\Documents\VKS Projects\secc-electron\src\views\main.jade'
var relativePath = myPath.replace(/.*(?=secc-electron)/, '');
```

The Regex is:

```
.*(?=secc-electron)
```

It matches any characters up to '`secc-electron`'. When calling `replace` it will return the last part of the path.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is to do a split (with regex or not):

Here's an example:

```js
var paragraph = 'C:\\Users\\susan ivey\\Documents\\VKS Projects\\secc-electron\\src\\views\\main.jade';
var splittedString = paragraph.split("secc-electron"); // returns an array of 2 element containing "C:\\Users\\susan ivey\\Documents\\VKS Projects\\" as the first element and "\\src\\views\\main.jade" as the 2nd element

console.log(splittedString[1]);
```

You can have a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp to learn more about this function.

Comment: This is also a very useful solution... thank you for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string at a certain point, then return the second part of the resulting array:

```js
var string = "C:\Users\susan ivey\Documents\VKS Projects\secc-electron\src\views\main.jade"

console.log('string is: ', string)

var newArray = string.split("secc-electron")

console.log('newArray is: ', newArray)

console.log('newArray[1] is: ', newArray[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `path.parse(path)`; https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path and retrieve the parts that you are interested in from the object that gets returned.